# StackOverflowException when loading Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceCollection (v6.6.0) with items while having TrackingMode.AutoChangeTracking

Tags: client, odata

I am trying to get entities from an ODATA service like this:

```
DataServiceCollection<Asset> entitiesServiceCollection = 
  new DataServiceCollection<Asset>(this._dataContext.Assets, TrackingMode.AutoChangeTracking );
```

The collection constructor throws the StackOverflowException unless I make TrackingMode.None.

This code used to work before switched the EF model-first data definition of the service side to code-first approach. Now, with the code-first approach the service looks fine but the client side is broken when it tries to use change tracking. Did I miss something during the model-first-to-code-first transition?

Here is how the Asset is defined:

```
public class Asset
    : EntityBase, IEntity<Guid>, IIdentifiable, IObjectStateHost, IAsset
{
    private Guid _id = Guid.Empty;
    private Identity _identity = null;
    private byte[] _content = null;
    private AssetContentKind _contentKind = AssetContentKind.Undefined;

    public Asset()
        : this(AssetContentKind.Undefined)
    {
    }

    public Asset(AssetContentKind contentKind)
    {
        _id = Guid.NewGuid();
        _identity = new Identity();
        _presentationalIdentities = new HashSet<PresentationalIdentity>();
        _contentKind = contentKind;
    }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id 
    { 
        get { return _id; }
        set 
        {
            _id = value; 
        }
    }

    public Identity Identity
    {
        get { return _identity; }
        set 
        {
            _identity = value; 
        }
    }

    public byte[] Content 
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set { _content = value; }
    }

    public AssetContentKind ContentKind
    {
        get { return _contentKind; }
        set { _contentKind = value; }
    }

    IIdentity IIdentifiable.Identity
    {
        get { return this.Identity; }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Utils.StringRenderingUtil.Render(this);
    }

}
```

Here is the call stack during the exception:

```
[Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.RuntimeType.GetGenericArguments()   Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsDataServiceCollection(System.Type collectionType, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model)    Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsEntityType(System.Type type, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model) Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsDataServiceCollection(System.Type collectionType, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model)    Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsEntityType(System.Type type, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model) Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsDataServiceCollection(System.Type collectionType, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model)    Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsEntityType(System.Type type, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model) Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsDataServiceCollection(System.Type collectionType, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model)    Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsEntityType(System.Type type, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model) Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsDataServiceCollection(System.Type collectionType, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model)    Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsEntityType(System.Type type, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model) Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsDataServiceCollection(System.Type collectionType, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model)    Unknown
```

...

```
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsDataServiceCollection(System.Type collectionType, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model)    Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsEntityType(System.Type type, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model) Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsDataServiceCollection(System.Type collectionType, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model)    Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsEntityType(System.Type type, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model) Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsDataServiceCollection(System.Type collectionType, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model)    Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsEntityType(System.Type type, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model) Unknown
Microsoft.OData.Client.dll!Microsoft.OData.Client.BindingEntityInfo.IsDataServiceCollection(System.Type collectionType, Microsoft.OData.Client.ClientEdmModel model)    Unknown
The maximum number of stack frames supported by Visual Studio has been exceeded.
```

I looked into the public source code of BindingEntityInfo - how the two recursive methods in the call stack are implemented. And it seems that the recursion may happen under a couple of conditions:

- either the data service collection is not getting to realize that its concrete T type Asset is an entity of the model,
- or the data service collection for some reason has no definition of the EDMX model in use.

That leads me to believe that I might need to feel in extra code-first settings/configuration when I move from perfectly working model-first to now broken code-first to fix it. The question is what are these "extra-settings"?

Comment: There's not enough information here to diagnose the problem.  Maybe your Assets collection is too large.  You could try posting the complete stack trace here, but we're probably going to ask you for more after we look at the stack trace.

Comment: I currently have up to 5 assets in my test setup.

Comment: Added the call stack to the original question...

Comment: Well, that was illuminating.  As you can see, an endless loop has been created between `IsDataServiceCollection()` and `IsEntityType()`.  The last line of the call stack tells the tale.  If it were me, I'd see if it is feasible to trace out that loop in a debugger, and try to find out why those two methods keep calling each other.  That could take awhile.

Answer (score 1):

I try to repro the problem. But it seems ok on my side. Here's my detail repro steps, hope it can help you:

**Use your Asset class to model, but remove the unknown types as follows :**

```
public class Asset
{

    private Guid _id = Guid.Empty;

    private byte[] _content = null;

    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
        }
    }

    public byte[] Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set { _content = value; }
    }
}
```

**Create the Context DB:**

```
public class AssetContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Asset> Assets { get; set; }
}
```

**Add the controller:**

```
public class AssetsController : ODataController
{
    private AssetContext db = new AssetContext();

    public AssetsController()
    {
        if (!db.Assets.Any(e => e.Id == new Guid("524BC73C-1545-4B5C-AD57-09B9FD8DB860")))
        {
            db.Assets.Add(new Asset
            {
                Id = new Guid("524BC73C-1545-4B5C-AD57-09B9FD8DB860"),
                Content = new byte[] {0, 2, 32, 64, 128, 255}
            });

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(db.Assets);
    }
}
```

**Test by running the service and querying the Assets. The result payload is:**

```
{
  "@odata.context":"http://localhost:52286/odata/$metadata#Assets","value":[
    {
      "Id":"524bc73c-1545-4b5c-ad57-09b9fd8db860","Content":"AAIgQID/"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Based on the [*OData Client blog*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/03/11/how-to-use-odata-client-code-generator-to-generate-client-side-proxy-class.aspx), build a console application.**

Test the OData Client as:

```
Container container = new Container(new Uri("http://localhost:52286/odata/"));

Console.WriteLine("Container created");

DataServiceCollection<Asset> entitiesServiceCollection =
       new DataServiceCollection<Asset>(container.Assets, TrackingMode.AutoChangeTracking);

Console.WriteLine("DataServiceCollection created");
```

**No exception throw.**

Comment: Sam, thank you! Yes, it does look very similar to my implementation and this is the blog post that I was originally following. Are you using ODataClient v6.6.0?

Comment: I check my application reference. My ODataClient version is V6.5.0